# Convert Anaconda and Spyder from Python 2 to 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I currently have Python 2.7 and need to fully convert my Anaconda and the Spyder IDE to Python 3.6. I have a testing environment currently in Python 3.6, but my root was installed and downloaded as 2.7. I do not need to preserve Python 2.7 capabilities. Before I mess up my Anaconda... do these steps make sense to convert my root to Python 3.6?

`source activate root
conda update conda
conda update --all python=3.6`

Would I need `conda update anaconda` and `conda update spyder`as well?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few options.

1. Update the current environment by installing python 3.6 into it. e.g.:

`$ conda install python=3.6`

Note that this will not work if you have any packages installed that are not python 3.6 compatible. If you *do* have conda packages that are not py3.6 compatible, you'll get errors like:

```
$ conda update --all python=3.6
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: ....


UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - enum34
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

And you'll need to go through and remove all of the offending packages.

2. Another option is to create a new conda environment with python 3.6 and spyder (and any other dependencies that you need).

   $ conda create -n py36 python=3.6 spyder ..

   $ source activate py36

   $ spyder
3. Final option is to remove your conda folder and then reinstall anaconda with python 3.6 or miniconda with python 3.6.

Comment: That first option with 'conda install...' and then 'conda update --all...' will update Spyder as well?

Comment: It'll update everything unless there are packages installed that are not python 3.6 compatible. There's also a way to undo changes in case something goes poorly: `conda list --revisions` and `conda install --revisions <revision-number>`. More detail [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35526770/3781327)

Comment: Ok great. Trying this out tomorrow afternoon, so I'll report back if all goes well!

Comment: I got the unsatisfiable error, and removed the enum34 package, but now am  getting "ImportError: No module named enum" no matter what conda command I use... Going to instead just uninstall and do a fresh install of Anaconda :/