# How can I downgrade the version pytorch from 0.4 to 0.31 with anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch

I'm using anaconda now and due to some code error I need to downgrade the pytorch from version 0.4 to version 0.31.
However, as I use anaconda as my python package management tool, I used the instruction below to downgrade it and encountered the following error:

`conda install pytorch=0.31 cuda80 -c soumith`

> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
>
> - pytorch=0.31

And I also have tried some normal method to revert the package into previous verion in anaconda, but they failed either.

Could anyone tell me how to downgrade it? Thank you so much!!

Comment: Uninstall the package and do ` conda install -c anaconda pytorch`, Conda website says that it will install 0.31, LINK : https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pytorch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I revert to a previous package in Anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974217/how-do-i-revert-to-a-previous-package-in-anaconda)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
conda install pytorch=0.3.1.0 cuda80 -c soumith
```

Answer (score 0):

https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/

This page contains all the info to downgrade Pytorch to the version you need.