# How to check previous installed version number of SciPy using Anaconda?

Tags: scipy, anaconda, version

I wrote some code months ago testing different optimizations of a function. I've since updated my anaconda installations of scipy, numpy, etc. that the code uses. Now the functions have different speeds (some faster, some slower), despite using the same code.

Is there anyway to check what the previous version of scipy that was installed was so I can attempt to see if something in scipy changed affecting my code? I use anaconda for package management, so I'm not sure if there's some record of previously installed versions somewhere. In particular I'd like to check cKDTree and cdist to see if either has changed in any meaningful way since my last installed version.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35526770/2449192

Comment: Yea I saw that post thank you. The problem is I don't know what my previous version was, which is what I'm trying to find out so I can do that. I guess I could just roll back to an older version and test it.

Comment: If you list the revisions, it will show you all of the previous versions. Unless it was upgraded multiple times, it should show you which older version you were using.

Comment: good to know. I ended up just removing and reinstalling anaconda so I lost all that fun ability now.