# Source activate fails for anaconda after update in base env

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

So these things happened:

I want to install `tensorboardx` and I have no idea that it may be a bad idea to install packages directly in `base[or root]` environment.
I ran `conda install tensorboardx` and agreed update to other packages. One of them is `conda`. (Seems I updated conda in this step)
After that when I run `source activate` in zsh, I get:`/share/apps/anaconda2/bin/conda:17: job table full or recursion limit exceeded`. Changed to bash and the same command silently failed.

So the question is how to let my anaconda back to work normally.

`conda -V` gives `conda 4.5.12`
Also I remembered the base environment is named `root` before this disaster.

`conda list --revisions` gives output:

```
2019-01-05 17:30:49  (rev 9)
     conda  {4.3.30 (https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free) -> 4.5.12 (conda-forge)}
     conda-env  {2.6.0 (https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free) -> 2.6.0 (conda-forge)}
     pycosat  {0.6.1 -> 0.6.3 (conda-forge)}
    +tensorboardx-1.6 (conda-forge)

2019-01-05 17:56:46  (rev 10)
     openssl  {1.0.2k -> 1.0.2l (https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free)}
    -tensorboardx-1.6 (conda-forge)
```

Comment: uninstall tensorflowx and then update the conda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the revision mechanism of anaconda. I ran `conda install --revision 8` and successfully reverted the operations, though I still have no idea what happened after I updated conda, possibly something got stuck in a loop.

[Further read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35526770/3057587)