# How to downgrade CUDA to 10.0.10 with conda, without conflicts?

Tags: python, pytorch, conda

I would like to go to CUDA (cudatoolkit) version compatible with
`Nvidie-430` driver, i.e., `10.0.130` as recommended by the [Nvidias site](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html).

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23974240/5986651) I did,

`conda install -c pytorch cudatoolkit=10.0.130`

And then I get [this error (pastebin
link)](https://pastebin.com/NG8hRY7N). (very-short version below):

```
(fastaiclean) eghx@eghx-nitro:~$ conda install -c pytorch cudatoolkit=10.0.130
...  
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: | 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed   
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package _libgcc_mutex conflicts for:
pyzmq -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex=[build=main]
libgcc-ng -> _libgcc_mutex=[build=main]
lcms2 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex=[build=main]
...  
The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__cuda==10.1=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__cuda==10.1=0

Your installed version is: 10.1
```

Why am I getting conflicts? Why does it say `10.1` when cuda toolkit
is `10.2.89` (`conda list`)? how to handle conflicts? What can I do
with this error? The conflicts are so huge, I don't know where to start.

**Other**

- Nvidia driver `430`
- current cudatoolkit: 10.2.89

Comment: I remember installed Pytorch via pip with incorrect Cuda version (10.1 vs 11) and it still worked. IIRC `pip install torch` also install `libcudarc.so` and other things with it too. If it works then don't fix it

Comment: pytorch and cuda might be compatible. But the thing is it is the nvidia driver (version-430) which doesn't work with 10.1 and above ([Nvidia website](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html#binary-compatibility)). Can you let me know a list of what you think I should install? What does "other things with it" mean? I am a noob. Should I also uninstall pytorch and cudatoolkit? or?

Comment: Nah, I just `pip install torch` back then and it installed cuda 10.1 which is not suppose to be usable on that PC. You should try `import torch; torch.zeros(1).cuda()` and see if it error or not. If not then it works

Comment: `AssertionError: 
The NVIDIA driver on your system is too old (found version 10010).`  I think this tells that Nvidia driver and cuda are not compatible. But, I can't increase my nvidia driver version as for ubuntu 16 it is only 430 (which is the latest).

Comment: So I tried to go to 10.0.130

Comment: Does `pip install torch==1.5.1+cu92 torchvision==0.6.1+cu92 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
` work? That's all I can help though

Comment: @natthaphonhongcharoen thanks for the help. I didn't try it... I wanted to stick with conda and see if I got a solution first and did find something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check current version with

```
torch.version.cuda
```

I had 10.2. But I need 10.1 according to: table 1 [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html) and my 430 NVIDIA driver installed.

**Uninstall and Install**

```
conda remove pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit

conda install pytorch==1.6.0 torchvision==0.7.0 cudatoolkit=10.1.168 -c pytorch
```

Say yes to everything for the above commands.