# Install cvlib package in python 3.9

Tags: python, installation, pip, package, cvlib

I am suffering as I couldn't install `cvlib` package in python 3.9
I have searched and found this link https://pypi.org/project/cvlib/#history which is the official link. The latest version is on April 11, 2020 and this seems older than the newer version of python
I tried `pip install cvlib==0.2.5` but this doesn't seem to work
How can I deal with such cases ..? I mean how to install those old packages in the newer version of python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alfie has stated, if the package was built for a specific version of Python, then it would be difficult to run unless you can make the changes yourself (if it's open source) and find the deprecated code and amend, or wait for an update from the developer.

With new releases, I always try and test them within a separate environment before introducing them to my root (in case it breaks something else). I use Anaconda and then create environments in there. In these environments you can then determine which version of Python and your packages can/should be used.

Some links that might be helpful:

[Managing environments in Anaconda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)

[Reverting to previous package in Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974217/how-do-i-revert-to-a-previous-package-in-anaconda)

[And also installing specific version (similar to above)](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/conda-essentials/installing-packages?ex=7)

Answer (score 1):

[Python 3.9 was released October 5th 2020](https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/3.9.html), there are probably lots of cases like this where modules aren't updated just yet. Downgrade to Python 3.8 if you are unable to use that module.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. Is there any workaround to make it available to install old packages instead of a downgrade?

Comment: @YasserKhalil No, to use a package that is made for Python 3.8, you have to use Python 3.8 for it to work.